# Nodejs Asynchronous function without parameter

Tags: node.js, http, express, asynchronous, rethinkdb

I am developing a rethinkDB Database and access it using an express server and using HTTP requests.

To get data from the database and then responding it to the HTTP request needs, as far I know, an asynchronous function.

Mine looks like that:

```
getChain(notNeeded, callback) {
        // Connecting to database
        let connection = null;
        rethinkdb.connect({ host: 'localhost', port: 28015 }, (err, conn) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            connection = conn;
            rethinkdb.db(dbUsed).table(tableUsed).run(connection, (err, cursor) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                cursor.toArray((err, result) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    // console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
                    console.log(result + "1");
                    callback(result);
                })
            })
        })

    }
```

And I am accessing it by:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    DatabaseBlockchain.getChain(('not needed'), callback => {
        res.status(200).json(callback);
    }) 
})
```

As you can see, there is a variable "not needed", that I don't need.
But when creating "getChain" without that second variable I can't call "callback(result)" at the end and get the error that "callback is not a function".

---

So, my overall question is, whether there is a way to create asynchronous functions without that second parameter!
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, thats possible. A callback behaves like every other argument.

```
getChain(callback) {
        // Connecting to database
        let connection = null;
        rethinkdb.connect({ host: 'localhost', port: 28015 }, (err, conn) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            connection = conn;
            rethinkdb.db(dbUsed).table(tableUsed).run(connection, (err, cursor) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                cursor.toArray((err, result) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    // console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
                    console.log(result + "1");
                    callback(result);
                })
            })
        })

    }
```

and then call it

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    DatabaseBlockchain.getChain(callback => {
        res.status(200).json(callback);
    }) 
})
```

Some things to note for you:

- Async error handling doesnt work with throw unless you use async/await.
- If you want to use callbacks, pass the error to the callback. By convention the first callback argument should always be error or null if everything went fine.
- have a look at promises and how they work

Comment: Wow, thanks! I thought I tried that but it seems like I changed something else too. Now it works great! Also thanks for your tips, I'll try to improve as much as I can!

Answer (score 1):

You must remove the "not needed" argument both from the function definition and from the function call:

```
getChain(callback) {
```

And:

```
DatabaseBlockchain.getChain(result => {
    res.status(200).json(result);
})
```